# Uploading a file to Google Cloud Storage is corrupted only when using Tika to get Content-Type

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, apache-tika

I am using the Google Cloud Storage Java SDK (`V.2.20.1`) to upload files to my Bucket.  I am trying to set the Content-Type of the file, which I am using Apache Tika to detect.  The issue is that if the use the Content-Type returned by Tika, even though it is correct, when the file is uploaded it is corrupted and I cannot view it.  If I manually set the Content-Type, the same value that Tika returned, then it uploads and I can view the file without issue.

This code does not work, I verify that the content type is exactly matching `applicaiton/pdf` but it is corrupted on upload and I cannot view.

```
Tika tika = new Tika();
String contentType = tika.detect(inputStream);
System.out.println(contentType); //"application/pdf"

if("application/pdf".equals(contentType)) {
     return bucket.create(Utilities.formatDirectoryName(directory) + name, inputStream, contentType);
} else {
     System.out.println("INVALID TYPE");
     return null;
}
```

This code does work by manually setting the Content-Type.  The file uploads and I can view it without issue.

```
String contentType = "application/pdf";
System.out.println(contentType); //"application/pdf"
if("application/pdf".equals(contentType)) {
     return bucket.create(Utilities.formatDirectoryName(directory) + name, inputStream, contentType);
} else {
     System.out.println("INVALID TYPE");
     return null;
}
```

When I view the information on the Cloud Storage UI everything shows correctly for both of the methods I listed above.  Content-Type, size, etc.  The difference is when I download the file to view, one does not work (corrupted) and the other one does work (views correctly).

[image]

I have run this test multiple times to ensure it wasn't just a weird upload glitch, but its consistent every time.   I have also tried this with different types of files such as Power Points.
Same result of using Tika vs manually setting the Content-Type.  This is driving me crazy, please help!

Comment: Tika should be resetting the stream after the call to detect.  How are you creating the InputStream that you are sending into Tika for detection?

Comment: @TimAllison I was doing something like this `new FileInputStream(new File("filepath")`.  I don't have the exact code anymore, but basically i was passing a `File` object into the `FileInputStream` constructor

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try to reproduce that behavior.  It is unexpected.  Typically, we recommend TikaInputStream.open(File file)...that will be more efficient on zip and ole2 based files (and PDF if you're parsing, which you aren't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using `Tika` messes with the `InputStream` marker, so once I run `detect` I can't re-use that `InputStream` to upload.

So instead I turn the `InputStream` into a `byte[]` then I can use that for detecting the type as well as saving

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
inputStream.transferTo(baos);
            
byte[] byteData = baos.toByteArray();
Tika tika = new Tika();
tika.detect(byteData);
```